# Toggle only content from clicked button in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to change display of `div.Filters` on click of **plus** or **minus** button. The button changes on click, if it's a **+** changes to **-**, and vice versa.

Here's the code:

```
export class NavLeftMobile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isToggle: true
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      isToggle: !this.state.isToggle
    });
  }

  render() {
    let button;

    if (this.state.isToggle) {
      button = (
        <button className="Menos" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          -
        </button>
      );
    } else {
      button = (
        <button className="Menos" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          +
        </button>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="NavLeftMobile">
          <h1>categories</h1>
          <h3>Manufacturer{button}</h3>
          <div
            className="Filters"
            style={{ display: this.state.isToggle ? "block" : "none" }}
          >
            <p>Lusograph (10)</p>
          </div>

          <h3>Color{button}</h3>
          <div
            className="Filters"
            style={{ display: this.state.isToggle ? "block" : "none" }}
          >
            <p>Black (10)</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, when clicking on one of the buttons, handleClick function is called and the display from `div.Filters` changes, if it's **block** to **none** and vice versa.
Basically, I want to toggle each section independent from each other.

Comment: Do you want to toggle each section indepently?

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: Yes, when I click one button, all sections collapse and I want only one of them to collapse depending on which button I clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each section to be Collapsible and indepent, then the state should not live on your wrapper component, instead you can create another class component that keeps track of it.

```
class Collapsible extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true
    };
  }

  onToggle = () => {
    const { collapsed } = this.state;
    this.setState(() => ({
      collapsed : !collapsed
    }))
  } 

  render () {
    const { title, children } = this.props;
    const { collapsed } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          {title}

          <a onClick={this.onToggle}>
            {collapsed ? '+' : '-'}
          </a>
        </h3>
        <div style={{
            display : collapsed ? "block" : "none"
          }}>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class NavLeftMobile extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="NavLeftMobile">
          <h1>categories</h1>
          <Collapsible title="Manufacturer">
            Lusograph (10)
          </Collapsible>
          <Collapsible title="Color">
            Black (10)
          </Collapsible>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavLeftMobile/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

Comment: Is the Collapsible a reactstrap component?

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro Collapsible is a component defined in the code provided by the example given. AngelSalazar basically created the component for you so that it's reusable and independent from each filter option.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ReyHaynes and thanks AngelSalazar for the code, it sure helped me!